# Inverse Hoeffding inequality for Rademacher random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

Let $Y_1,\dots,Y_k$ be independent and identically distributed Rademacher random variables, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(Y_1=1)=\mathbb{P}(Y_1=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$, and take $p\in \mathbb{R}^k$ with $||p||_2=1$.

I want to prove the following inequality: $\mathbb{P}(\sum^k_{i=1}Y_ip_i>x)\geq e^{-cx^2}$, where $x\geq a$ and $x\leq b(||p||_{\infty})^{-1}$ and $a$ and $b$ are some positive constants.

I know the Hoeffding inequality and that this inequality is basically the inverse version. How could I approach this problem?

Comment: Just want to make it clear. What are you trying to capture using two constants $a, b$? Just want to have a lower bound for the tail probability? Do you recognize the tail probability vanishes for $x > \sqrt{k}$?

Comment: The main thing is the probability inequality. The two constants are there, but its not that I am really interested in these. Maybe I can precisely find out their value but its not of importance. They are more or less there such that the inequality works.